# Widget World to S30 Conversion

Tags: conversion

I understand that Widget world is no longer operating.
I have had to get a Hamilton bard cylinder that uses an s30 thread.
This is not compatible with the widget world devises.
Can anyone tell me the thread that widget world used and I have a
widget world trigger device that screwed on to the widget wold cylinders and had a thin plastic pipe that connected to the inlet of my pressure gauge attached to my king keg barrel.
can anyone tell me how I can use this ( widget world trigger device) with a Hamilton bard (s30) cylinder.
I lot of people would also like this answer and have asked me to pass the answer on to them.
Cheers - Ian Paterson
31/03.17

Answer (score 1):

Ian, is this the kind of device you are looking for: http://brewingathome.co.uk/product/midget-widget-world-universal-barrel-hose/